# When using gulp-sass 4.02 in my gulpfile.js, my task runner explorer in visual studio 2019 fails

Tags: visual-studio, gulp-sass

In my gulpfile.js I'm using gulp-sass pulled in via package.json ("gulp-sass": "4.0.2").
This (var sass = require("gulp-sass");) prevents the visual studio 2019 task runner explorer from recognizing my gulp tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to harski in this github thread https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/759, the solution was simple:

Add "node-sass": "4.13.1" to the paskage.json